# for - else vs for elif

Tags: python, for-loop, python-2.7, if-statement

i thought that elif: was the shorthand for

```
else:
     if:
```

but it's not possible to use

for - elif:

only

for - else: if:

in this code:

```
for line in source:
    change_next = False
    for dataset,artnr,revision in datasets:
        if dataset in line:
            change_next = True
            print "  **  " + dataset + " found"
            datasets.remove((dataset,artnr,revision))
            break
    else:
        if line.startswith("DstID:"):
            print line.replace("DstID:","").rstrip()

    if change_next and "Partno:" in line:
        destination.write("Partno: " + artnr + "\n")
        print "Partno: " + artnr
    elif change_next and "Revno:" in line:
        destination.write("Revno:" + revision + "\n")
        print "Revno:" + revision
    else:
        destination.write(line)
```

Thanks for the response so far, my question now is rather: is this the way to do it? if a line does not have any (of the known)datasets in it, then i want to print it if it is a dataset?

Comment: I've been programming Python for about 7 years and I never knew about the `else` clause in a `for` statement...

Comment: @AndrewJaffe: That's understandable. It's not particularly useful. I think there have been only a handful of times when I've used it.

Comment: @JoelCornett I use it all the time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`elif:` isn't a macro that expands to `else: if`, it is a syntactical element that is valid only in the context of an [`if:` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement). Ordinarily, `else: if` would open a new `if` block; however, `elif:` doesn't do that.

Comment: Which is lucky, because otherwise we couldn't have multiple `elif` clauses in one `if` statement, which would be awful!  (... I suppose unless subsequent ones expanded to *increasingly indented* `else: if` blocks, which would just be bizarre... Wow, I need to bleach my brain now.)

Comment: But it would make sense to have `elif` after a `for`, right? To me the fact that we can do `for ... else`, but no `for ... elif ... elif ........... else` seems inconsistent.

Comment: How would it make sense to have `elif` after a `for`? The `else` after a loop doesn't do the same thing it does with `if` (and that's confusing).

Answer (score 10):

The [`for` `else`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) is a special case usage, not the same as the [`if` `elif`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement) structure.  `elif` doesn't really make sense in the context of `for` anyway, as the meaning of the `for` `else` is "if we have completed the loop without breaking, do this thing".  That's binary logic.  `elif` doesn't make sense in the context of this binary decision.

Comment: There's also `while` `else`, but it's used even less often than `for` `else`.

Comment: @MRAB `elif` doesn't make contextual sense in `while` `else` either.  Or in `try` `except` `else` for that matter.  Point is that `elif` doesn't exist in those contexts because it doesn't make logical sense for it to.

Comment: To me `elif` does make sense in a `for ... elif ... else` context. Think of it as equivalent to `for ... else if ... else`. What does not make sense about it? I know python syntax does not allow it. I am saying that *semantically* it *could* make sense.

Answer (score 9):

Correct.  The same goes for `else` in `try .. except .. else`.

Answer (score 5):

The 'else' you refer to is tied to the 'for' command, not to an 'if' command. 'elif' only makes sense when used with an 'if' command.

With the 'for' command, the 'else' block is executed only if the 'for' block is not prematurely ended by a 'break' command, see [paragraph 4.4](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html).